# Nginx. Чтение файлов уровнем выше

Tags: nginx, настройка

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос, собственно, в следующем:

Имеются два сайта на одном домене. Один расположен в корневой папке домена, а второй в виртуальной подпапке. Конфиг nginx

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.example.ru;
        root /var/www/example;
        index index.php;

        location / {

            root /var/www/example;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api.php?_d=$1&ajax_custom=1&$args last;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;

            location /catalog {

            root /var/www/example;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
            }
        }
```

В итоге открываются оба сайта под адресу example.ru и example.ru/catalog

Но!

example.ru/catalog ищет картинки, файлы js и т.д. в каталоге /var/www/example/catalog, которого не существует. Все его файлы лежат уровнем выше (/var/www/example/). Как заставить подкаталог смотреть на уровень выше, чтобы он увидел все нужные файлы?

Спасибо!

Upd:

Получилось решить часть проблемы, добавив ниже

```
location ~ ^/catalog/(.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|svg|ttf))$ {
            alias /var/www/example/$1;
        }
```

После этого необходимые файлы стали видны.

Осталась проблема с аргументами, идущими после index.php

Пример: `https://example.ru/catalog/index.php?dispatch=ab__grid_tabs.load&block_id=298&result_ids=content_ab__grid_tab_2379_298&is_ajax=1`

Выдает 404 в консоли. Из-за этого пропадает часть функционала и контента сайта https://example.ru/catalog

Сам файл index.php физически находится здесь: `https://example.ru/index.php`

Возможно ли решить такую проблему через конфигурацию nginx?

Comment: alias вместо root

Comment: @andreymal если поставить alias вместо root, то example.ru/catalog перестает открываться с ошибкой 404

Comment: Если это два разных сайта, значит лучше продублируйте файлы и не выпендирвайтесь)

Comment: @andreymal если бы это было реализуемо, я бы пошел по пути наименьшего сопротивления и не стал бы тут спрашивать.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Не могли бы вы пояснить, почему это не реализуемо? Сейчас с моей точки зрения вы пытаетесь сделать что-то ненужное, зачем — пока не понимаю. Если внутри /catalog отдельный сайт, зачем ему ссылаться за пределы себя? Если не такой уж и отдельный, то пусть в его страницах будут прописаны нормальные относительные ссылки вида `../index.php` без всяких nginx

Comment: @andreymal так завещали потомки. :D это нужно для мультимагазинов в cscart. Проблему решил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, изменив в location

c

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
```

на

```
#   Логика поиска скрипта по порядку: файл, папка, скрипт
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$3 /$2/$3 $3 @fallback;
```

где

```
location @fallback {
        rewrite  ^/(\w+/)?(\w+/)?(.*)$ /$1/index.php?$args last;
        rewrite  ^/(\w+/)?(\w+/)?(.*)$ /index.php?$args last;
    }
```

Со статикой помогло это:

```
location ~* /(\w+/)?(\w+/)?(.+\.(jpe?g|ico|gif|png|css|js|pdf|txt|tar|wof|woff|svg|ttf|csv|zip|xml|yml)) {
            access_log off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$3 /$2/$3 $3 @statics;
            expires max;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
        }
```

где

```
location @statics {
        rewrite ^/(\w+/)?(\w+/)?(.*)$ /$1/$3 break;
        access_log off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$3 /$2/$3 $3 @fallback;
        rewrite_log off;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
```